# How to set Id of one entity to the Id of another entity using JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm new at Spring Boot's JPA concept so need your help in deciding how to import just the `ID` of another entity, say `User` into `HealthData` entity. Following is my `User` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email")})
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Email
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private String imageUrl;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean emailVerified=false;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @NonNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthProvider authProvider;
    private String providerId;
}
```

And I wish to define `HealthData` entity in the following manner :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "HealthData",uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")})
public class HealthData {
    @Id
    private Long id; //how to import id of User here?

    @Column
    private Double height;
    @Column
    private Double weight;
    @Column
    private int age;
    ...other columns

}
```

Now, I wish to use `Id` of `User` to this entity(kind of making parent-child relationship) . I don't want to add `User` class object in HealthData. I thought of using `@OneToOne` in `HealthData` but then it would add `User` in it. How can i just include Id from parent table in child table?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is how ORMs work. If you don't want it you should consider to use plain JDBC or a lightweight mapper like MyBatis.

Comment: This appeared the way to go as it would limit the loading of unnecessary objects to optimize performance. I'm just starting with Spring boot and JPA. So i thought just importing Key instead of whole object would be quiet efficient.

Comment: Your suggestion is to import whole ```User``` object and let ```HealthData``` have it's own Id generated independent of ```User's id```?

Comment: You should learn more about your JPA implementation. You can usually control how related objects are loaded. Look here to get an idea: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-eager-loading. But you should be very careful. It depends on the use case which fetch type is appropriate. You may run into the [N +1 select problem](https://medium.com/geekculture/resolve-hibernate-n-1-problem-f0e049e689ab).

Comment: When using ORMs the most straight forward procedure is to have individual IDs for each table. Even in plain SQL you wouldn't reuse the same IDs in multiple tables to model a one to one relation. This coupling would be too tight. You would always use a separate field in one table with a foreign key to the other table's ID.

Comment: you need some way to tell JPA about this relationship so that it can set the values for you. I don't know why you would NOT have a user in or associated to HealthData; the relationship seems like it is pretty fundamental to the data and the objects. Can you elaborate on why, as that seems like your best bet; without a relationship, this is just like any other column data that you'll have to figure out and set yourself, possibly with a persist user, flush, then pull out the ID to use in a HealthData instance - a much less efficient option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your HealthData has a reference to User, and I'm not sure why you wouldn't have mapped this as a foreign key. If you are able to do so, I'd suggest the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HealthData")
public class HealthData {
    @Id
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user; 

    @Column
    private Double height;
    @Column
    private Double weight;
    @Column
    private int age;
    ...other columns
}
```

JPA then handled setting the "ID" to the value within your user instance for you, and can persist both in the same transaction automatically. Allowing references to be marked as IDs is known as a derived ID and supported I believe since JPA 2.0.

As for efficiency, you can still lazy fetch or even not fetch the user instance. It is simple to just map the ID column as a basic using a slightly different approach:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HealthData")
public class HealthData {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user; 

    @Column
    private Double height;
    @Column
    private Double weight;
    @Column
    private int age;
    ...other columns
}
```

JPA will set both the User id as well as the healthData.id values based on what it generates for the user Id sequence when you set the healthData.user reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use getters and setters to set the value of user id in the healthdata table.